# multi-select drop-down results shows Array

Tags: php

im using multi select drop down list im able to select the list i want to update in my database but when i see the results it shows "Array" Instead Of the Selection.

```
 <select class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true" name="Attendedby" ng-model="Attendedby">
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

```
$('select').selectpicker();
```

[image: this is mysql preview]
[image]

i dont know why my results display Array, please help

Here is my php

```
        if($form_data->action == 'Edit')
        {
            $data = array(
                ':Attendedby' =>    $Attendedby,
                ':EndDate'    =>    $EndDate,
                ':Status'     =>    $Status,
                ':Remarks'    =>    $Remarks,
                ':id'         =>    $form_data->id
            );
            $query = "
            UPDATE cov9 
            SET Attendedby = :Attendedby, EndDate = :EndDate, Status = :Status, Remarks = :Remarks
            WHERE id = :id
            ";

            $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
            if($statement->execute($data))
            {
                $message = 'Data Edited';
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: PHP code, where is it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to edit the name of the `select` to `Attendedby[]` as it expects multiple values and then use something like this to get multiple data into one column:

```
$Attendedby = implode(', ', $_POST['Attendedby']);
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21562528/1554060)